# Wordpress change the limit of the number of posts just for mobile

Tags: wordpress, posts, syndication-feed

I have the WP backend setting - `Blog pages show at most` set to 20.

I want to override this setting in my PHP in case that the user agent is mobile.

One way that I had in mind is -

```
    $iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
    $android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
    $ipad = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
    $berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
    $ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
```

Then I thought to do something like

```
    if ($iphone || $android || $ipad || $ipod || $berry == true)
```

and then set the new post limit to 10.

Is it anyway possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What benefit do you expect? An RSS feed is just an XML document. The bandwidth you are saving is probably negligible, especially when the response by your server is properly gzipped.

Comment: At the moment I have 20 posts on the Homepage. Once going with mobile, I thought it might take less time to load, as every post has images etc. If there would be just 10 posts, isn't it half of the bandwidth?

Comment: Frontpage is not the same as the feeds. Please check http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds and http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_Screen

Comment: Stupid me. I meant the BLOG settings. `Blog pages show at most`. I've now edited the first post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','change_limit_mobile');

function change_limit_mobile($query){

    $new_limit = 10;

    $iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
    $android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
    $ipad = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
    $berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
    $ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");

    if (( $iphone || $android || $ipad || $ipod || $berry ) && $query->is_main_query()){
        set_query_var('posts_per_page',$new_limit);
    }
}
```

This will override the posts per page based on the value of `$new_limit` variable in all your loops. If you want to target only the home page, Then you can add `if(is_home())` in the condition too.

Comment: I've added this to my functions.php but I don't understand how to implement this code fully. Do I need to use `$new_limit` somewhere? My loops are set with the `$paged` variables so maybe there is a conflict?

Comment: `pre_get_posts` ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts ) is fired before every query is run. So you do not need to use `$new_limit` variable anywhere. It will automatically override the default 20 to 10 posts per page.

Comment: Thanks @chiragswadia! 
I will try to use this code instead of mine. Maybe after your edit it would work. Last time I checked it didn't work but I based my solution on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it in a different way.

On the page where I want to limit the total number of posts I set the `$new_limit` to be 20 on default (As I want 20 posts per page). Then, I added the condition when it is mobile.

```
<?php
$new_limit = 20;

$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$ipad = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");

?>
```

Then the limit is set to 10, only on mobile.

```
    <?php if ($iphone || $android || $ipad || $ipod || $berry == true){
    $new_limit = 10;}?>
```

Finally, I added this into my `WP_Query`:

```
    'posts_per_page' => $new_limit,
```

Works perfectly as far as I tested

Comment: This will work fine, But you will have to use this code on every loop then. Using `pre_get_posts` eliminates this drawback, and you will have a common code for all loops at one place without you having to check for mobile always in each loop individually. If you need this at only one page, then your solution is pefectly fine :) I have given a generalized solution in my answer above.